# how to use c# regex to fetch substring between recognized patterns?

Tags: c#, regex

My c# code stores a text.

I want to fetch some words without a known pattern which appear among words with known patterns.  I don't want to fetch the words with the patterns.

i.e.

```
My company! 02-45895438 more details: myDomain.mysite.com

can I fetch like this?
<vendorName?>\\s*\\d{2}-d{6}\\s*more details: <site?>
vendorName = "My company!" or "My company! "
site = "myDomain.mysite.com"
```

Is there any way to do so with regex?

Comment: What exactly do you want to be the result of the match? The whole `02-45895438 more details: `?

Comment: I want to fetch vendorName = "My company!" or "My company! "
site = "myDomain.mysite.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is the syntax I was looking for:

```
(?<TheServer>\w*)
```

like in:

```
 string matchPattern = @"\\\\(?<TheServer>\w*)\\(?<TheService>\w*)\\";
```

see
http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes%E2%80%94Extracting_Groups_from_a_MatchCollection

Answer (score 0):

from your description, it seems like you want to find "myDomain.mysite.com" from the string "My company! 02-45895438 more details: myDomain.mysite.com", if that's the case you can use a regex simmilar to this one to get the string you want

```
(?<=My company! 02-45895438 more details: ).*?
```

that should give you the substring based on the preceeding match, but will ommit that from the capture.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using parentheses. For example, this will give you the contents of a bold tag:

```
<b>([^>]+)</b>
```

You can then use Regex.Match to get a Match object, then get the groups via Match.Groups. Each group is a set of parentheses, so in this case there's one group that contains the tag's content.

Comment: Better explanation of what this does:

First, matches opening b tag, then opens a group, then matches any number of characters that isn't <, then closes the group, then matches a closing b tag.

Comment: You forgot the group 0, which contain the whole match. So, in this case, the code in parentheses will be in group 1.